# VS2019 typedef changing when including <random>

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Here I have a method which returns a vector:

```cpp
std::vector<uint32_t>& GetElements() const noexcept
{
    return m_Elements;
}
```

And when I'm assigning the result to a variable:

```cpp
auto& elements = object.GetElements();
```

And hovering over `elements`, VS2019 says that it's type is: `std::vector<std::seed_seq::result_type>`, after searching for defenition it shows that it is the same type (`unsigned int`). It only happens when I have random lib included, as it comes from it. My questions are: Why does it happen? Why does IntelliSense change one typedef to another: `uint32_t` to `std::seed_seq::result_type>`?

Comment: It's a variable with `std::vector<uint32_t>` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just IntelliSense™ being somewhat less than intelligent! Both `std::seed_seq::result_type` and `uint32_t` are defined as `unsigned int`, so I guess it's getting confused as to which one to show. (Presumably, the actual compiler has no such problem, and your code compiles without error.)

From `<stdint.h>`:

```cpp
typedef unsigned int       uint32_t;
```

From `<random>`:

```cpp
class seed_seq { // standard sequence of seed values
public:
    using result_type = unsigned int;
    //...
```

Comment: So that's just an IntelliSense thing?

Comment: Yep. At compile-time, the 'alias' is resolved, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The typedef names are not real and don't show up in the actual mangled names etc.  But it's a royal pain to see a huge template expansion when we know it as a simple name like `string`.  So Intellisence is finding that a simple alias exists for a type and using it.  It doesn't know that that name is only used by *some* code; it just finds a simpler name for the same type and uses that.

If you [look at the generated code](https://godbolt.org/z/s6cjbjnT9) without this kind of helpful re-interpretation, you see its name is actually `std::vector<unsigned int,std::allocator<unsigned int> >`.